# For loop appending wrong Value

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement

Hey guys I'm missing something here I want to append  'a' to my answers if the two values match and 'b'
if they don't but it always appends 'b'

so the number before the word should be equal to the length of the word

```
import re

def is_a_valid_message(message):
answers = []
x = re.findall(r"([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)", message)    
for k  in x:
    y = len(k[1])
    z = k[0]
    if y == z:
        answers.append('a')
        print(k[0], k[1])   
    else:
        answers.append('b')
        print(k[0], len(k[1]))   
print(answers)
```

The first test string is "3hey5hello2hi"

which outputs

```
3 3
5 5
2 2
['b', 'b', 'b']
```

I

Comment: Is it possible, that you are comparing string "z" with the integer "y"? And that is why the if condition is always false?

Comment: "3" == 3   is  False

Comment: ahh man I see it now i guess i assumed that when i grab the number with the expression it was an int

Answer (score 0):

try this. You need to compare the string with the string.

```
import re

def is_a_valid_message(message):
    answers = []
    x = re.findall(r"([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)", message)    
    for k  in x:
        y = str(len(k[1]))
        z = k[0]
        if y == z:
            answers.append('a')
            print(k[0], k[1])   
        else:
            answers.append('b')
            print(k[0], len(k[1]))   
    print(answers)
```

Comment: That has certainly got me closer to where I want to be, thanks! Got a few other things to change. why is it that comparing the two values which clearly are the same are not appending to the list ?

Comment: Well, k[0] returns "3" which is a text that contains the character "3". len(k[1]) returns integer of value 3. Python cannot compare text with number. You need to convert number to text and then compare text with text. OR convert text to number and compare number with number.

Comment: got it mate thanks i never thought of it that way i guess because they look the same in the output. that's going to really help me alot in other things too thank you